# CellMouseClick dont work when click second time on check column

Tags: c#, winforms

When i click second time on check button this code is dont work.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) // pin
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pin"].Value.ToString() == "False")
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Cells["Pin"].Value = CheckState.Checked;
        }
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pin"].Value.ToString() == "True")
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Cells["Pin"].Value = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }

    }

}
```

[image]
Help me please.

Comment: What is happening? Do you get an error or unexpected behavior? Which?

Comment: You are changing next row checkbox (why next?), but the one what was clicked will never change, the second `if` is never `true`.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you're trying to achieve? Do you want to allow the selection of a single CheckBox only? Something else?

Comment: I want to press one check box and after that i need that another check box become pressed. 
I dont have any error.
It work if i go out from cell field.
But if i press checkbox second, third e.t.c. time without exit from cell field another checkbox is not working.
--
Sorry for small information.